# On premise Kubernetes cluster has pods unable to reach the internet

Tags: kubernetes, dns

I've created a new k8s cluster in a couple of VMware nodes, following this guide:
https://computingforgeeks.com/deploy-kubernetes-cluster-on-ubuntu-with-kubeadm/

After the installation the cluster is up and running, and the master and the node are READY.
So I've created a couple of Pods but I discovered that no one can reach the Internet.
In order to debug I've created the dnsutils Pod (from the Kubernetes page) and
logged into it with "kubectl exec -it pod/dnsutils bash"

If I do a "ping 8.8.8.8" I cannot get any response.
So is it possible that a classic kubernetes installation end up with a cluster unable to reach internet?
What is the fix to do in order to have Pods that "see" Internet?

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

\sergio

Comment: 1) host nodes able to reach 8.8.8.8?  2) how is your coredns pod doing in kube-system namespace ?